# Maximum length of Facebook album name and wall post?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

What's the maximum length for an album name and a wall post allowed on Facebook? Will the PHP SDK automatically trim it?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/

Comment: @MarcB are you able to find "maximum" or "length" in the album description here? Have you at least opened that page? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook's api will take care of truncating any length of data. The api only limits you to data types, as in strings and integers.

That being said, it is very hard to develop for Facebook if you do not have an account, if not simply to access the documentation, or register for and API key, or just plain testing things out. You can create a dummy account, and have nothing public.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was looking for an answer like this. Where did you find this information? And for development it's exactly what i'm doing: fake account and testing.

Comment: It is not documented anywhere, I know from my own trials and tribulations in using Api's for Facebook, Twitter, etc. I think they do not publish lengths and such, just incase they change something internally (on the DB side) they do no need to change it in the thousand of documentation files. They just handle the validating and length requirements on their end, and truncate it friendly style if it exceeds what they are expecting.

Comment: Facebook is not truncating data anymore. It throws exceptions, in case you're using Graph API. Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735947/what-is-maximum-message-length-for-facebook-wall-post-closed/11736523#11736523